# Shell multiple condition statement using OR

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following number in a text file

`9378123456
93700805040
0700801902
0093700809102
93711592456
3937389393`

I am trying to write shell script to print all numbers that are not started with `9370` and `9371`
here is my script

`number="$(< all_numbers.txt)"
for numbers in $number; 
    do

      if [[ (! ${numbers} =~ ^9370 ) || (! ${numbers} =~ ^9371) ]]  ; 
          then

              echo $numbers ; 
          fi; 
       done`

but it seems i have something wrong on my if condition result to wrong  output as follows:

`9378123456
93700805040
0700801902
0093700809102
93711592456
3937389393`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to become more friendly with [De Morgan's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). You may have been mislead by the wording *"all numbers that are not started with 9370 and 9371"*: a number cannot start with both 9370 *and* 9371 -- what is meant here is a number which does not start with 9370 *or* with 9371.

- You want to select print a number if it does not begin with 9370 or 9371. The condition is

  ```
    not ((number matches ^9370) or (number matches ^9371))
  ```
- Which by De Morgan's formulas is equivalent to

  ```
    (not (number matches ^9370)) and (not (number matches ^9371))
  ```
- So in your script you should have

  ```
    if [[ (! ${numbers} =~ ^9370 ) && (! ${numbers} =~ ^9371) ]]; then
      echo $numbers  
    fi
  ```
- Not to mention that for the toy problem you could of course write

  ```
    if [[ ! ${numbers} =~ ^937[01] ]]; then
      echo $numbers 
    fi
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy job for such good tools as `grep`, `sed`, `awk`:

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Eo "^937[01][0-9]+$" all_numbers.txt
```

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -rn 's/^937[01][0-9]+$/\0/p' all_numbers.txt
```

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^937[01][0-9]+$/' all_numbers.txt
```

The output would be:

```
93700805040
93711592456
```